# kafka describe consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using  kafka-0.10.2.0-rc2 version. I am wondering is there anyway to check current offset of the consumer group where no consumer is active in the group.

I tried to use the **kafka-consumer-groups.sh** to describe but it is always showing the following message

```
Consumer group `<group_name>` is rebalancing.
```

I even checked the kafka sourcecode, this message is expected where no consumer is active in the group.

snipcode: **ConsumerGroupCommand.scala**

```
protected def describeGroup(group: String) {
      adminClient.describeConsumerGroup(group) match {
        case None => println(s"Consumer group `${group}` does not exist.")
        case Some(consumerSummaries) =>
          if (consumerSummaries.isEmpty)
            println(s"Consumer group `${group}` is rebalancing.")
          else {
            val consumer = getConsumer()
            printDescribeHeader()
            consumerSummaries.foreach { consumerSummary =>
              val topicPartitions = consumerSummary.assignment.map(tp => TopicAndPartition(tp.topic, tp.partition))
              val partitionOffsets = topicPartitions.flatMap { topicPartition =>
                Option(consumer.committed(new TopicPartition(topicPartition.topic, topicPartition.partition))).map { offsetAndMetadata =>
                  topicPartition -> offsetAndMetadata.offset
                }
              }.toMap
              describeTopicPartition(group, topicPartitions, partitionOffsets.get,
                _ => Some(s"${consumerSummary.clientId}_${consumerSummary.clientHost}"))
            }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Seems the code you paste is from 0.10.1.x instead of 0.10.2 because 0.10.2 is able to describe empty groups.

Comment: you are correct! I have pasted wrong code, Thanks

Comment: I want to develop the service to monitor the consumer group offset, and also to detect if consumer is not able to pick the message as we are facing the problem with consume is not able to pick the message from last offset. if is happen a notification will be sent to support for action taking?

is there any Java api to check that information? thanks